# Represent data as Fourier-transformation or polynomial with high degree?

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, polynomials, continuous-fourier

I am dealing with stelar light curves (.fits-files containing 4000 datapoints of time vs stelar brigthness, see graphic for a few examples with different periodicity). I need to represent/fit these lightcurves in a way that allows me to perform on them unsupervised clustering with machine learning. I got suggested to use either a polynomial representation with a high degree (p=30...up to a few hundreds) or to use fourier transformation on the lightcurves. I found that polynomial fits of numpy.polyfit with a high degree p don't provide good fits and I receive a warning "RankWarning: Polyfit may be poorly conditioned". Maybe I should try Fourier-transformation, but I am not familiar and it sounds complicated.

How can/should I represent/fit such data for the sake of machine learning clustering? Can I achieve a good result with np.polyfit with p>30?
[image]

Comment: This is a very general question! SO is only for when you have tried something and have errors in your code.

Comment: I saw other stackexchange users asking general questions, for the sake of getting PRINCIPAL advise how to built their code, what methods to use, ect. I hope to get similar advise.

Comment: @anishtain4: This is consistent with other questions in machine learning and related groups: OP specifically asks about data representation to serve a particular function call.  Yes, it would be better to have a specific example of the warning message.

Answer (score 1):

For things with a clear "seasonal" recurring cycle, Fourier transformation seems much more adequate.

Just imagine you get more data. You'd want the representation to be stable, and somewhat predictive of this obvious temporal pattern. A polynomial doesn't do this well, it would likely need new terms all the time.

But of course there are other alternatives: DCT, wavelets, etc. - there are entire books on handling such data.

Comment: Indeed, I am facing the problem you mentioned regarding expending the data, which requires new polynomial terms. Can you point out what python packages I should take look at? Some exaples/code templates? Book recommendations? Tnx